# Two widgets one next to other in linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I'm feeling difficult to implement , two widgets(say spinner) in linear layout one next to the other. I mean layout height of both spinner is wrap content, but width should be first half for the first spinner, second half of the screen to the second spinner. In linear layout they coming one down the other. I tried in Relative Layout, but as i gave width as wrap_content both are coming one next to each other but lot of space is remaining right to second spinner. I have seen in few apps this working out, but im not getting it.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`layout_weight`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_weight). This will force the two spinners to take up half of the space each.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    ... >

    <Spinner
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ... />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No. It is a `horizontal` layout, so the weight will be applied horizontally.

Comment: In my layout i had one more spinner like in above diagram, so i used one more linear layout within it and set it orientation to horizontal. I'll post that answer,but that is inspired by your answer so i'm accepting yours :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the EXACT same problem one day. I've also tread a lot of different tricks to get it working. I ended putting both spinners in their own layout. Was weird but it worked.

Comment: I think i can do by mentioning explicit size..but thats not right way to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

relative layout is intended for putting views related to each other . it has nothing to do with their sizes.

for linearLayout , set the height/width (depending on orientation of the layout) of both views to 0px and the weight to 1 . this will make each take half the space.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/testArray" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:entries="@array/testArray" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>     
</LinearLayout>
```